# I bundle update'd to Rails 4.0 by accidents, how to undo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, bundle, ruby-on-rails-4

I had the following near the top of my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails'
```

I'm using rails 3.2.x and now when I ran `bundle update`, I got upgraded to rails 4.0 which I'm not ready for yet.

Can I simply delete my Gemfile.lock file, add the version number to `gem 'rails'` in my Gemfile and re-`bundle install`?

Comment: Yes, delete Gemfile.lock, specify rails version in Gemfile, then `bundle update`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can simple delete the gemfile.lock and re-bundle install,
or, add version number to rails and then do

```
bundle update.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using git please do this.

```
git checkout -- Gemfile.lock
```

Comment: I would love to use this method, but I have *.lock ignored in my .gitignore

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can just delete the lock file, add the version to `'rails'` and run `bundle install`.

AFAIK, that should do it.

Comment: Isn't the question "Can I simply delete my Gemfile.lock file, add the version number to `gem 'rails'` in my Gemfile and re-`bundle install`?" Anyway, ok, I'm making it somewhat more verbose, give me a minute.  edit: Done

Comment: Ah, that was a reply to someone who said I didn't answer the question, not complaining to you or anything. And don't worry about the right answer thing, it's not like I care a lot about that when answering. I'm glad it all worked well on your end.